# Android: Parse HTML (not XHTML) progressively like XmlPullParser?

Tags: android, html

I have searched for "Android HTML parse", but all the results were about `Jsoup`. `Jsoup` seems to be loading the whole `HTML` into memory at once. Is there a way to parse `HTML` progressively from an `InputStream`, as `XmlPullParser` does (but probably `XmlPullParser` is not usable because it is not `XHTML`)?

Comment: @AmilaSenadheera Don't misuse backticks for emphasis.